# Facebook invitation request is not delivered

Tags: objective-c, facebook, dialog, apprequests

I am showing a dialog in an iOS app to allow users to select some friends to whom send an invitation to the app.
The dialog is displayed, you can select some friends and press send.

Dialog delegate method callback is called successfuly.
So far so good, but the friend is not receiving any invitation, 
is that because the app is still in development?

This is the code I am using to show the dialog, is there any missing parameter?
(access token is fine because the app works).

```
// Show the UI Dialog
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   kFacebookAppID,@"access_token", @"Invitation message", @"message",nil];

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests"andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495462/presentrequestsdialogmodallywithsession-does-not-work-but-gives-good-result/16654666#16654666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests are only delivered if the user can reasonably be expected to accept them; if your app is only an iOS app (i.e no canvas implementation / apps.facebook.com URL) then they'll only be displayed in the Facebook app for iOS.

If this isn't happening it may be because your SSO settings for the app aren't correct, so Facebook's app doesn't know how to bring users to your app when they accept the request, check those first - making sure the URL handler is set up correctly in your app, etc.

It may also be because the app is in sandbox mode, but i'm not sure about that one.