# How to invite facebook friends for app request notification?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, friend, invite

I have a **non game app** and I want to invite my facebook friends by send notification.
Facebook Platform Upgrade from last few months, check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) link.

Now How can I send invitation to friends?

should I use sharing wall post instead of invitation.

Thanks.

Comment: Invitations are fine to use. Just Facebook won't issue notifications until your app is live on the App Store (until you don't have live app store id).

Comment: Hey @UserDev! have you got any way for it , i have  same issue , so please send any answer, if you have

Comment: It's not possible for non game app, you can only use invitation feature for game category app.

Answer (score 0):

You can send invitation even now :

try this code....

```
[FBWebDialogs
         presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
         message:@"YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE"
         title:nil
         parameters:nil
         handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
                 NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
             } else {
                 if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                     // User clicked the "x" icon
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                    NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                        }
             }
         }];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes I checked it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495462/presentrequestsdialogmodallywithsession-does-not-work-but-gives-good-result     but will it facebook allow for NON game app. have you read facebook invite api?

Answer (score 0):

use this code you can invite your 
facebook script section.

[Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui).

```
<script>
document.getElementById("apprequest").onclick =  function(){

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE'
    }, function(response){
        alert("Success");
  //console.log(response);
    });

}
</script>
```

HTML section

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root">

<button id="apprequest" name="btnLogin" >App Request</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I am looking for iOS native app and second above code is for sharing not for invitation.