# Custom Facebook iOS request dialog with sdk v3.19 and Graph API v2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to figure how a custom invite/request dialog can be created in the new Facebook iOS SDK.

So far I only found the use of [FBWebDialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBWebDialogs) to create request dialog but it's not customizable AFAIK.

In [this sample](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.1) there is an explanation on how to do that but it doesn't help me because:

1. It's java script API.
2. It talks about the invitable_friends API while "The invitable_friends API is only available for games that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation using version 2.0 of the Graph API" which my game [Thingies](http://thingies.mobi/app?v=SOFI) is only available in iOS.

So the questions are:

1. Can a Requests dialog (FBWebDialogs ) be even used in an iOS game that has no presence on Facebook Canvas?

   Because [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app) it says that an app that does not have a presence on Facebook Canvas may use the Message Dialog on iOS, not the requests dialog, but [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1#invoking) it doesn't restrict FBWebDialogs in iOS to games with Canvas (if it does restrict what will happen when you do use the FBWebDialogs after april 2015? an Exception?!?)
2. How a request dialog be customized in facebook iOS SDK 3? e.g. like
   in here:
   [image]

   3. Can you send a request in this dialog to friends that are not playing the game?
   4. After you select them and send the request, will it open a send request dialog for confirmation? e.g. like in here:
      [image]

Thank you all!

Comment: If you don't have a canvas app you can not build a dialog like that. The options you have are listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: Cannot build a customizable requests dialog, or cannot even use the requests dialog for invites?

Comment: Correct. You need to use the send or share dialog