# how can i get fb friend list in new facebook SDK for ios.

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to get Facebook friends list in my iOS application and want to send a invitation. But in new SDK i can only get the friends which are already using application.

Comment: Try my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495462/presentrequestsdialogmodallywithsession-does-not-work-but-gives-good-result/16654666#16654666

Answer (score 0):

Note That facebook **me/friends** got only thats friend who install or use the same app . not get all friends. if you apps is created before 30,April-2014 ,then **me/friens** got all friends.

If you apps type is GAME then you can invite your friends using **invitable_friends** graph API.

See Facebook invitable_friends API  : [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/invitable_friends)

you can also get all friend list using Facebook **taggable_friends** API

See Facebook taggable_friends API : [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends)